# Strip all whitespace from a string

Tags: go

What is the fastest way to strip all whitespace from some arbitrary string in Go.

I am chaining two function from the string package:

```
response = strings.Join(strings.Fields(response),"")
```

Anyone have a better way to do this?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Why would you infer that? I'm asking about the best/fastest way to do a general operation. I don't see the problem with my question.

Comment: If I'm trying to parse a given input as efficiently as possible it usually helps to know what that input is. Why would I infer that? Because you omitted the relevant information.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Ok, well I've clarified that I am asking about any arbitrary string.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Here is some benchmarks on a few different methods for stripping all whitespace characters from a string: ([source data](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2264/pg2264.txt)):

```
BenchmarkSpaceMap-8                     2000       1100084 ns/op      221187 B/op          2 allocs/op
BenchmarkSpaceFieldsJoin-8              1000       2235073 ns/op     2299520 B/op         20 allocs/op
BenchmarkSpaceStringsBuilder-8          2000        932298 ns/op      122880 B/op          1 allocs/op
```

- `SpaceMap`: uses [`strings.Map`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Map); gradually increases the amount of allocated space as more non-whitespace characters are encountered
- `SpaceFieldsJoin`: [`strings.Fields`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Fields) and [`strings.Join`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join); generates a lot of intermediate data
- `SpaceStringsBuilder` uses [`strings.Builder`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder); performs a single allocation, but may grossly overallocate if the source string is mainly whitespace.

```
package main_test

import (
    "strings"
    "unicode"
    "testing"
)

func SpaceMap(str string) string {
    return strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
        if unicode.IsSpace(r) {
            return -1
        }
        return r
    }, str)
}

func SpaceFieldsJoin(str string) string {
    return strings.Join(strings.Fields(str), "")
}

func SpaceStringsBuilder(str string) string {
    var b strings.Builder
    b.Grow(len(str))
    for _, ch := range str {
        if !unicode.IsSpace(ch) {
            b.WriteRune(ch)
        }
    }
    return b.String()
}

func BenchmarkSpaceMap(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        SpaceMap(data)
    }
}

func BenchmarkSpaceFieldsJoin(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        SpaceFieldsJoin(data)
    }
}

func BenchmarkSpaceStringsBuilder(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        SpaceStringsBuilder(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm guessing this avoids allocating those extra strings between the Join and Field calls?

Answer (score 81):

I found the simplest way would be to use [strings.ReplaceAll](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ReplaceAll) like so:

```
randomString := "  hello      this is a test"
fmt.Println(strings.ReplaceAll(randomString, " ", ""))

>hellothisisatest
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/EEKNqz2PBeL)

Note: This does NOT remove all types of whitespace and this approach is limited to removing a single character type with each call.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question correctly. I was not looking for the "most simplest" way to remove just spaces. I was looking for the fastest general method to remove ALL whitespace.

Comment: stringvar = strings.Replace(randomString, " ", "", -1)

Comment: This does not strip other whitespace like newlines and tabs.

Answer (score 3):

From [rosettacode.org](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Strip_a_set_of_characters_from_a_string#Go) :

You can find this kind of function :

```
func stripChars(str, chr string) string {
    return strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
        if strings.IndexRune(chr, r) < 0 {
            return r
        }
        return -1
    }, str)
}
```

So, simply replacing `chr` by `" "` here should be enough to do the trick and remove the whitespaces.

Beware that there are other kind of whitespaces defined by unicode (like line break, nbsp, ...), and you might also want to get rid of those (especially if you're working with external data you don't really have control over)

This would be done that way:

```
func stripSpaces(str string) string {
    return strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
        if unicode.IsSpace(r) {
            // if the character is a space, drop it
            return -1
        }
        // else keep it in the string
        return r
    }, str)
}
```

Then simply apply to your string. Hope it works, didn't test.

Answer (score -1):

I use Regexp for removing all white spaces on a `[]byte` or an `string`.
Example for buffer of `[]byte`:

```golang
    buf, err := ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    r, _ := regexp.Compile(`\w+`)
    words := r.FindAll(buf, -1)
    // TODO
```

Example for an small string:

```golang
    r, _ := regexp.Compile(`\w+`)
    words := r.FindAll([]byte("\n\thello\n\r\r\tworld\n"), -1)
    // TODO
```

Always we should find a simple, already thought and bug fixed solution instead of implementing them.

Comment: Since this question is specifically about speed, how does this compare in terms of speed / performance to the solutions benchmarked in the accepted answer?

Comment: Additionally, this answer is incorrect as `\w` is not synonymous with all non-whitespace characters, only a limited subset of them. The correct regex to use here would be `\S+`. Also since you will end up with a set of slices you will need to join, it is likely that this sufferes similarly slow performance to the the SpaceFieldsJoin solution in the accepted answer.

Answer (score -4):

I assume this was added since the question was asked years ago:

```
strings.TrimSpace(moo)
```

"TrimSpace returns a slice of the string s, with all leading and trailing white space removed, as defined by Unicode."

See https://pkg.go.dev/strings#TrimSpace

Comment: trimming from the beginning and end is not the same as stripping all occurences so this does not answer the question.

Comment: @Omn My answer might help some people, we'll see. If you wanted to "strip all whitespace" from a person's name, you wouldn't delete all spaces, you would delete the unnecessary whitespace because spaces are part of the name. You're reading the question literally. Great. Often whitespace refers to extra, unnecessary non-visible characters. Another example, HTML ignores whitespace, but that doesn't mean you can delete all spaces.