# I want to remove whitespace in sentences

Tags: go

```
import "strings"
formatted_text := strings.TrimSpace (unformatted_text)
```

I want to format the text obtained by scraping.

In this way, leading and trailing whitespace can be removed, but whitespace in sentences is not.

How can I easily remove white space?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strip all whitespace from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081808/strip-all-whitespace-from-a-string)

Comment: That helps a lot.
Thank you for the quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use strings.ReplaceAll

```
s = strings.ReplaceAll(s, " ", "")
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
However, line breaks and tabs could not be removed.

Comment: Try ReplaceAll(s, “\t”, “”) probably you need to consistently cause the replacement of all unnecessary characters

Comment: Thank you very much.
It seems that it can be done by connecting ReplaceAll and removing each one